# Changing color to status bar

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

Ok I am still learning this...
I have Googled and done some research but did not find what I am looking for.
I'm trying to Add a status bar, which displays the current color in the background. This should update regardless of how the user changed the background color (Context menu, Menu bar, Buttons).

I already added the status bar, but I am not too sure on how to get it to display when you click on the button with the color or when you use the context menu. So I have to go in each one of those code to change or make a public class with the status bar.

Below you can find an image of what I intend to do:

[image]

If you look on the bottom it say red background and it is also highlighted to red. When I click on the blue or the green I need it to change over also.
What would be the best way to accomplish this?

This is my code from the `toolstrip`:

```
 private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        
    }

    private void toolStripButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    }

    private void toolStripButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
    }
```

This code is from my context menu:

```
 private void redToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }

    private void greenToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    }

    private void blueToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
    }
```

I am trying to figure out the status bar right now.

Edit I figure out what I had to do. I needed to go back on my form page and edit the toolstrip. Thanks for the help guys and girls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to react to the background color change of your main form. You can do this either by handling BackColorChanged event or overriding OnBackColorChanged protected method in your main form class.

Answer (score 2):

Make all the buttons use the same event. And then check the sender. If you assign greenButton, blueButton etc tags to the buttons then you can use this:

```
private void ColorButtons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control item = (Control)sender;

    if(item.tag == "greenColor")
        this.BackColor = Color.Green;
    else if(item.tag == "blueColor")
        this.BackColor = Color.Blue;
    // and so on
}
```

Comment: well the button are at the top with there colors already there. So would I have to make a new private void event?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Read it again.

Add that code to your Form and then select each button and use that Event. Also, add "greenButton,blueButton" etc to the names of the buttons.

Comment: I will not downvote this, but this solution is bad if you have to do it for 20 colors.. also the name should be irrelevant some way.. maybe using the tag property of the control? or even better, just pick up the background color of it ;)

Comment: @gbianchi: Oh yea. That's a lot better. I haven't worked with Windows Forms in like an year so I didn't remember that. 

Edited the code.

Comment: One solution in this case to avoid names would have been to take the background color of the buttons.  This way, you are sure they will match :-)

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a method to change the color, and in this method, set the text and/or color of your status bar.

So instead of setting (for instance)

```
this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
```

you'd call

```
this.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.Blue);
```

and in `SetColor(Color)`, you handle the text change.

For instance, you could use this method :

```
private void SetColor(System.Drawing.Color c)
{
    this.BackColor = c;
    this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = c.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Altough you are not using a good method rigth now (other answers have better methods), you can easily fix it. Since you want to change the background color of a control inside the status bar, you can do it in several places:

You can have a function that change that receive a color and change the control according to that. In your example, the label on the strip bar is red, and you already change it on designer. Well, at runtime you can do the same, using code ;). the label has a name. just add a function something like this:

```
private void ChangeColor(mycolor as System.Drawing.Color)
{
    yourlabelcontrol.BackColor = mycolor;
    yourlabelcontrol.Text = mycolor.Name;
}
```

You can also execute this on every action that change a color.

You can have one function that change the color of everything (like this one, but change the color for everthing)